# How can precision be improved for the debug log timestamp?

Tags: php, core

Sometimes, I write info to the debug log to diagnose problems.  While working on a performance problem, resolution to hours:minutes:seconds is not enough.  I'd like to get to milliseconds, but haven't yet found the place to make the change.  Ideas?

FWIW, this is what the default timestamp looks like: [08-May-2020 23:16:38 UTC]

THANKS for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not manage the format of the timestamp.  Instead, WordPress hands off error message contents to the PHP function error_log(), which creates the timestamp.

Finding no easy way to ask [error_log()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) for higher resolution timestamp, combined with the fact that I'm creating the message content myself, I've added a microsecond string ahead of my messages, essentially like this:

```
error_log( gettimeofday()['usec'] . ' ' . $message );
```